# Strange comments in new users' profiles

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Today, the new user profile was instituted. It seems good, although the revised layout will take a little while to get used to.

However, I noticed that for new users, there are some strange comments in unpopulated fields. [For example](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/27788/jen?tab=profile):

[image: "Apparently, this user prefers to keep an air of mystery about them."]

And:

[image: "We respect a laser-like focus on one topic"]

I suppose these flippant comments are meant as a joke, but to be honest, I was confused by them at first (especially the first one, which appears where users would write their own profile information).

Overall, I'm not sure if it's a good idea to have content in the profile that the user hasn't chosen for themselves, and which more than likely does not accurately reflect their intentions in becoming a member of the site. My preference would be to remove the first text and show nothing in that position, and change the second text to "(No posts yet.)" or something similar to that.

Thoughts?

Comment: This is a Network-wide change therefore this question belongs on Meta Stack Exchange.

Comment: I guess it was closed as a duplicate of another similar question there. I'll reopen it here to give our users a chance to weigh in (not that it's going to matter since it looks like SE/Jaydles has already decided on what the outcome should be).

Comment: @rm-rf Which question was considered the original?  EDIT: found it: [(251810)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/251810/)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard thanks for doing the migration; it was the appropriate action on your part but the question was immediately closed as a duplicate despite the inadequate answer. Re-opening did not last, so I thought I'd just delete to save any further useless discussion over whether it's a duplicate or not. I did not really think about it being reopened here as a result of my deletion. I can delete this one too perhaps if nobody has anything to add, but I would think the more sites that raise this as a problem, the more likely we will get a good response.

Comment: @rm-rf sorry, thanks, you were so quick that I hadn't noticed it wasn't automatic. Obviously it's their site/business so they can do whatever they want, but I just think this is comes across as very unprofessional. A refusal to meaningfully respond to criticism about it doesn't really help in that respect.

Comment: @OleksandrR. I for one agree with you. +1

Comment: @OleksandrR. Note that your [comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251810/the-site-should-not-make-speculative-statements-about-its-users#comment828292_251814) on the Mother Meta has a broken link - gives me a 404.

Comment: @episanty yes, it's because I deleted the question after it was closed as a duplicate for the second time. As long as we have one place to raise this (per site?), that's enough, I think.